# D3 Zoomable sunburst visualization without size define in json children

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
 {
  "name": "TOPICS",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Topic A",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Sub A1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Sub A2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Topic B",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "Sub B1"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Sub B2"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Sub B3"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

root = d3.hierarchy(root);   
root.sum(d => d.size);
```

Given that I do not use size in json (as seen above), my question is this:
**how can I render and generate sunburst visualization**?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
var root = d3.hierarchy(root, function(d) { return d.children })
    .sum( function(d) {       
                if(d.children) {
                    return 0
                } else {
                    return 1
                }
        });
```